# Pass function to Bokeh Slider

Tags: python, bokeh

I've been working on an interactive Bokeh plot with sliders (basing it on the Bokeh repo Slider App example), and am playing around with having the data update according to different functions. This is straightforward when hard-coding the function into the update_data() method of the app. One thing I'd like to do is pass a lambda function to the app, at creation and have the data update according to that function based on the slider values. The ultimate goal is to automatically generate an interactive plot, where the interaction is based on some function selected by the user (though once the plot is generated, the interaction will remain the same).

What I've tried so far is to make a class level attribute of type Function (from bokeh.properties), and then assign the passed lambda to this class attribute (which is then accessible by the update_data() method). I then create the app with the lambda as a passed argument:

```
my_func = lambda x: x**2
SliderApp.create(my_func)
```

However, when I try this and then navigate to the URL I get the following error:

```
TypeError: <function SlidersApp.create.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x106b09158> is not JSON serializable
```

Are there any recommendations on how to work around this, or perhaps a better to approach to the problem at hand?